# Drupal 7 "post_articles" module missing

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to start a Drupal 7 website. I was provided with a folder containing a Drupal installation, and was to move it to a server with a database supposedly for that installation.

Upon me doing so, Drupal gave me several errors regarding missing modules. After manually installing most of the missing modules, I am left with a single error, which is

```
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: post_articles. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page.
```

I am unable to find the post_articles module on the Drupal website or anywhere else, and am at loss how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a contrib module so you cannot get it from drupal forge, otherwise to unlock your situation you can disable module by query into your database :

```
UPDATE system SET status=0 WHERE name='post_articles';
```

But it can be a dependency of another module so be careful when you're disabling module with this way.